# Out of Stack Space error in Jquery UI slider initialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, slider

I am using Jquery UI slider in my Asp.net application.
I am using jquery version (1.10.2) file.

Below the line to initialize a Jquery slider inside a javascript method.

```
function SetSliderValues() {
    if (initialLoad == 1) {
        var minVal = 5;
        var maxVal = 10;
        try {
            $("#slider-range").slider({
                range: true,
                values: [minVal, maxVal]
            });
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert(e.message);
       }
    }
```

It is working fine. But some time I am getting `Out of stack space` exception while executing `$("#slider-range").slider ...` line.

I have called an ajax method before "SetSliderValues" method.

Kindly suggest a solution.

Comment: Note that the `values` array should contain numerical values.

Comment: edited question.Some times minVal and maxVal have fractional values

Comment: Do you still get the error with the updated values?

Comment: Not for all time.But some time I am getting the error. also I have called couple of ajax methods before "SetSliderValues" method.